# Hashing and using time as salt to prevent access from un-authorized system and replay attacks

Tags: security, sha, hmac, hmacsha1

I am currently writing a user authentication API for a mobile game. I'd want to make sure that the user can only access the system from the mobile app. (That is, the server has to deny access if the Server API is accessed from browser or CURL (un-authorized system) even though the exact POST parameters are valid). Ideally, the system should not allow replay attacks as well.

Does anybody have idea or example of how this can be done?

I am thinking of adding a unique-per-user salt with current timestamp and SHA256-ing the parameters with a private key on the client app, which will then be validated on the server. This way will prevent the access from browser or CURL as attackers will need to get the private key in order to compute the SHA256 hash. The salt (which includes timestamp) will also be sent as one of the params, and the server will get the timestamp and deny access if it is past a certain time. But I am not very sure about the security and whether it is the common or correct practice, as I've never design secured app, or seen the source code of one before.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This will stop users from intercepting requests on network and using them with CURL. But both private key and signature algorithm can be extracted for your app and reimplemented, so this solution will not be totally secure.

Alas, you can't have complete security here without some custom tamper-resistant hardware issued to users.

Comment: thanks for the input! I won't be worrying too much about players who try to extract the key from the app, as I am generating the key on the fly based on a few key-like strings (a few of the strings are dummy to trick the hackers). I just need to make it a little bit difficult for most players to shy away